# How to reset memory usage after Azure Function runs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've implemented memory profiling into my Azure Function, received a python 137 error, went to check the memory usage and found that the memory usage will slowly increase. Most of the time it will reset, but sometimes it doesn't and I'm assuming it's hitting the RAM cap on the function.

Here is the highest the memory usage got before throwing that 137 error:
[image]

Is this enough to warrant a 137 error? If so, is there a way I can reset the memory usage after each invocation manually?

Comment: Why not use a serverless approach? Otherwise it seems your app itself doesn't dispose properly after each use

Comment: @misha130 Hey, I thought Azure Functions were serverless. I believe I'm on the consumption plan as well, but how would I check to make sure? Also, yeah it doesn't seem to, but I assumed after each invocation the memory would reset and I wouldn't have to do anything on my end. Doesn't seem like that's the case though, and I'd like to know what I should do. I am running a blob storage trigger function with python btw.

Comment: Well, AzF can be not serverless too if you designate a server for them. But generally it looks like a memory leak. Pretty difficult to say the reason for it without any code

Comment: Ah okay, I don't believe I have designated a server for it, but I have scaled the number of units that can run the function to 1 if that makes any difference. I'm pretty ignorant on how memory leaks could happen, but here is what is going on inside: 1. Read in blob 2. download blob to memory, and create a data frame with it 3. Export it out to db. After those steps are done and the function exits, I figure the memory should be reset in preparation for the next invocation, but it doesn't seem to be happening sometimes. Is there a way I can be sure to make that happen?

Comment: Inside my program I'm storing the downloaded blob into a variable, I could use the ```del``` statement to delete the variable after I'm done putting it into a data frame. Does that sound like a good idea @misha130

Comment: You are doing `using` on the memory stream?

Comment: @misha130 I am not

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to delete the temp files.

> Unlike Persisted files, these files are not shared among site instances. Also, you cannot rely on them staying there. For instance, if you restart a web app, you'll find that all of these folders get reset to their original state.

So, you can just restart your function app in order to reset memory usage.

**From portal:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**REFERENCES:** [Understanding the Azure App Service file system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files)

Comment: The OP is using Python, also, not knocking the answer but isn’t this kinda dangerous if an existing invocation is still running? It’s a curious answer. Very interesting.

Comment: Thank you @Skin for letting me know. Just went off the topic on that restart part. And yeah, haven't really given a thought if we could really do that.